# how to get thumbnail view of given html code, using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using ckeditor to create email templates, I'm trying to get a thumbnail view of a given html code.

I have tried with

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('templatecontent'),{
   onrendered: function (canvas) {         
    var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.open(imgString);                  
}});
```

But here id(#templatecontent) is hidden textarea element. How to save an image even if the id is hidden.

**Or**

Can this operation can be done directly with php if I have html code? this will be great. Please give me some suggestions or procedure to follow.

**Error details:**
IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $html = @file_get_contents('Myvoucher/'.$_POST['filename'].'.html');

    $getFileCommonContents = @file_get_contents('voucher_common.html');
    $getFileCommonContents = str_replace('[MAIN_CONTENT]',  $html,      $getFileCommonContents);
    $html = 'htmlfiles/'.$_POST['filename'].date("Ymd").time().'.html';
    @file_put_contents($html,$getFileCommonContents);
    $target_html_file_url = 'http://xx.com/prakash_rd/'.$html;
    $phantomJs = 'jsfiles/'.$_POST['filename'].date("Ymd").time().'.js';
    $target_image_file  =   'images/'.$_POST['filename'].date("Ymd").time().'.jpg';
    $phantomScript              =   "var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1343,
    height:12996
    };
    page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36';

    page.onLoadStarted = function () {
        console.log('Start loading...');
    };

    page.onLoadFinished = function (status) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            phantom.exit();
              // Do something after 5 seconds
        }, 5000);
    };

    page.open('".$target_html_file_url."',function (status) {
        page.render('".$target_image_file ."', { format: 'jpg', quality: 90 });
        phantom.exit();                                     
    });";

            @file_put_contents ($phantomJs, $phantomScript);        
            $command                    =   'phantomjs '.$phantomJs;
            @shell_exec($command);  
            if(file_exists($target_image_file))
            {
            //  unlink($phantomJs);
            }
```

Comment: <img src="imgString" width="yourwidth" height="your height" style="display:none" id="imgid"/>  html2canvas(document.getElementById('templatecontent'),{
   onrendered: function (canvas) {         
    var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   $('#imgid').attr('src', imgString ); $('#imgid').show()             
}});

Comment: As I mentioned in question, It is showing error, if i'm giving hidden element #templatecontent

Comment: Ah okay. Use phantomjs just send html code along ajax post method request and saved as html page and run the page using phantomjs with php shell command and get screenshot with giving your path

Comment: @PHPDeveloper please amend your question using the Edit function, not through badly formatted comments.